# Recursively Defined Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, coloring

I'm having trouble with a recursively defined graphing problem. However, I think I partially have the correct solution. The problem asks me to find $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$ using the recursively defined formula:

1. $O_1$ is two isolated nodes.
2. $O_{n+1}$ is created from $O_n$ by creating two nodes and and connecting with an edge each node to all nodes in $O_n$.

Now I need to draw $O_1$, $O_2$, and $O_3$. My drawing for $O_1$ is simply two nodes (with no edge between them). $O_2$ is a bipartite graph consisting of four vertices, and $O_3$ is a bipartite graph consisting of six vertices.  [Are these correct?]

The next part of the question asks to determine the chromatic number $\chi(O_n)$ for $O_1$, $O_2$, and $O_3$. My solution is: $\chi(O_1) = 1$, $\chi(O_2) = 2$, and $\chi(O_3)=2$ (since I think the last two are bipartite). [Are these correct?]

Now the final part of the question asks me to determine a formula for $\chi(O_n)$. This part I'm confused about because it seems to me that the list of chromatic numbers $\chi(O_1) = 1$, $\chi(O_2) = 2$, $\chi(O_3)=2,...,\chi(O_{n+1})=2$. Any help would be awesome for this part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$O_3$ is not a bipartite graph: if $vw$ is an edge of $O_2$, and $x$ is one of the new vertices added for $O_3$, then $\{vw,vx,wx\}$ are all edges.

Comment: Thank you! This all now makes much more sense since the chromatic numbers will increase instead of staying constant. I needed to draw my picture more clearly.